# Using "while this is the case for only" to compare and contrast two facts

Tags: phrase-usage

*1. While 26% of the immigrants said that they entered the UK for academic pursuits, this is the case for only 4% of emigrants.*

*2. While 27% of the world's forests are in Africa, this is the case for only 9% of global timber production.*

So I was once advised not to use **"this is the case for only"** to compare and contrast two situations. But I don't really know why it's not okay because it sounds perfectly fine to me in the first example.

I'm not so confident about the second sentence, though. Maybe because I feel like **"this is the case for"** is more appropriate in situations involving stronger verbs than just "**are**". So could you tell me if the phrase works well in these two examples or not?

Comment: I'm not sure that your situations are exactly parallel. If you mean '4% of _emigrants_ said they entered the UK for academic pursuits', that doesn't make sense, since emigrants _leave_ a country.

Comment: I assume 1 means "4% left the UK for academic pursuits"; it does require a little thought to decode. 2 seems more natural than one, since both the forests and the timber production are in Africa, and the case is genuinely the same; although that doesn't mean 1 is invalid. Anyhow [to be the case](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/to-be-the-case) is on Collins' website with lots of examples so I don't really understand the grounds or details of the prohibition.

Comment: @StuartF - Well, I assume that too, but the sentence needs rethinking to make sense. It is definitely **not** the case that any emigrants 'entered the UK' for any purpose!

Comment: Yes, the idea is like what Stuart said.

Comment: So it seems that I can use this phrase right? I still don't understand why one of our senior admins didn't think that this was a valid phrase to compare two facts. He didn't give me any specific reasons :<